# Better approach to find Overlapping through multiple Time intervals

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm, data-modeling

The Goal here is to get the Agenda of multiple users. And match users who share the same free-time.

For performance reasons, I expect Mysql (or any alternative) to do the job. So the task of buddies matching would be executed via a trigger or a Server' Cron Job.

```
    |userId|agenda                                        |buddies
    |22    |{"week":[ "36-42", "49-52", "68-73"]}         |9,6,23
    |23    |{"week":[ "26-32", "61-70", "68-75","79-85" ]}|9,5,22
```

My idea is to assume all free-time ranges are recurrent events on a weekly basis. And any exception would be handled differently.

I think a unique identifier for each hour in a week (Base 168) would avoid extra daily loops
So time intervals could be translated in something like following :

```
{"weekly":[ "36-42", "49-52", "68-73" ]}
```

I'm used to time interval overlap with Date ranges. But here I'd like to find any possible intersection of multiple ordered intervals with different dimensions.

After `JSON_EXTRACT`, is it possible with MySql to find the intersection and return its  UserId ?

Following this approach, and using new Json functions, which DBMS would better handle such data structure? Mysql or Sqlite?

Any different view or an alternative data model is welcome :)

Comment: Your approach of using JSON (thus detracting from 3NF) and then still expecting MySQL to be the performant solution for this problem is unreasonable at best. At worst it is absurd. The more reasonable approach would be to normalize the data such that instead of storing non-scalar data inside a single column, you can store a normalized row per event/busy-time as a range using intervals (such a UNIX timestamp), for example. This then can be more easily scanned for overlapping gaps using `BETWEEN` clause, for example. You may need further filtering to find a gap large enough, but it's a start.

Comment: Simply put, this is the same scheduling problem something like Google Calendar tries to solve by normalizing the time intervals to 5 minute blocks (thus reducing the amount of data necessary to compute a wide range over a large group of overlapping calendars. Further performance boost can be achieved by caching the schedules into a compressed bitmap such that simple pointer arithmetic (`XOR` in this case) can be performed on the bitmaps to do the calculation in polynomial time.

Comment: I thought json would be a clear format. Actually I was thinking of converting ranges objects into something Mysql would handle.  I think Unix timestamp for recurrent events would require extra tables to define periodicity. it's more of an arithmetic algorithm i'm looking for here. Json is the best format to store arrays... But i'm still brainstorming :) why even arrays?  Thx for the caching tip by the way

Comment: Reframing your problem, it is basically the same as finding all available rooms in a hotel for a list of dates (e.g. the list of available times of your current buddy). That's a relatively [popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=find+free+room) and those should provide you with ideas, data structures and code. It seems less like an algorithmic problem but more of a problem of how to store (and maybe cache/precalculate/prepare/...) your data (and, as Sherif pointed out, storing the data as json will probably not be a very common choice).

Comment: `via a trigger or a Server' Cron Job.` why?

Comment: @Strawberry this could be used in an API where we send a userId and get a list of matching IDs. Only Oracle and Postgresql have a definition
or Array Datatype and because Not all DBMS are capable of iteration through Json objects (like Json_each in Slqite), I was thinking a Mysql function would be used in a trigger.
This function would be exectued only on (Insert/Update/Delete).
Once a match found, we would just easily parse his agenda.

Comment: And as Sherif mentioned, 
the concept is to find a minimmized Flat alternative to the Third normal form when we don't extra relational functionalities (like a RangeId or RangeType ...)

@Solraflare That's right most of rooms bookings, cars rentals and any Time Range overlapping are using that model.
And I'm just looking for an alternative :)